# How to query SQLite by integer?

Tags: android-sqlite

I have a SQL table like the following:

```
ID(string)    Name(string)    Width(double)   Height(double)   Selected(int)

12345678      Book            210             297              1
12345679      Display         530             326              0
12345680      Phone           70              140              0
```

I can query them by ID and Name by passing a String argument without issue, but all int and double queries return null. Why?

This is the code I tried:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(  "Objects",null, "Selected" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)},null,null,null);
ObjectDataBase.ObjectCursor objectCursor = new 
ObjectDataBase.ObjectCursor(cursor);
try {
    if (objectCursor.getCount() == 0) {  return null;  }
    objectCursor.moveToFirst();
    return objectCursor.getObject();
} finally { cursor.close();}
```

`ObjectDataBase` is the Database class, and `ObjectCursor` is the cursor wrapper and inner class of `ObjectDataBase`.

When I peek through the database using DB browser, the data is correct, so what else can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> When I peek through the database using DB browser, the data is
>   correct, so what else can be wrong?

### a) The data in DB Browser may not be the data on the device.

- This is a frequent cause of issues.
- To rule this out I'd suggest running the query without the select clause so that all rows are returned along with some basic debugging

such as

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query("Objects",null, "Selected" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)},null,null,null);
Log.d("CURSORINFO","The Cursor has " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()) + " rows."); //<<<<<<<<<< 4 DEBUG
DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor); //<<<<<<<<<< 4 DEBUG

ObjectDataBase.ObjectCursor objectCursor = new 
ObjectDataBase.ObjectCursor(cursor);
try {
    if (objectCursor.getCount() == 0) {  return null;  }
    objectCursor.moveToFirst();
    return objectCursor.getObject();
} finally { cursor.close();}
```

- If the first message in the log reports that there are 0 rows, then you have no data in the table.
- If you do have data in the table then the output from the **dumpCursor** method will output all of the data. You need to check that it matches what you expect the table to hold.
- If the data matches the expectations then re-introduce the select clause and rerun. A row count of 0 and the issue is then with the select clause.

### b) Wrapping code in a try clause

- This can hide useful information if there is an underlying exception.
- Your code would be better as :-

  ```
  ObjectType rv = null;
  if (objectCursor.moveToFirst()) {
      rv = objectCursor.getObject();
  }
  cursor.close();
  return rv;
  ```
- If an exception happens then you will know about it.

### c) The Cursor wrapper code is incorrectly assigning values.

- As the code is not included in the question then it's impossible to say anything other than check the code.

Comment: if I try this code Cursor cursor = ObjectDataBase.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM `Objects` WHERE selected = 1", null); cursor return 1 row which is correct. \n However if i try Cursor cursor = ObjectDataBase.query(  "`Objects`",null, "selected" + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)},null,null,null);cursor return 0 row.See the problem why second code style doesnt work??